# Email migration from a directly owned and operated server to a hosted service

Tags: email, migration, imap

My company sells subscriptions to some offline services, which include a complimentary email 1 Gb email account with POP/IMAP access. Roughly 2000 users use this service.

Right now, we operate this email service directly, but as part of streamlining the company, it appears it would be less costly in both time and money to outsource it to a hosting provider.

The steps to proceed with the transfer are well-identified:

1. Mass-create the accounts in the provider's system using its API
2. Transfer emails stored on the current server into the new accounts
3. Point the domain MX to the provider's system

I need advice with step 2: as I do not have direct access to the provider's system, I have to find a way to transfer the emails using either POP/IMAP/SMTP.

I was thinking IMAP: considering the current server as an IMAP client, cycling through the accounts, I wonder if there is a way to force-synchronize the provider's system with what is stored on the client?

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Often the hosting services you are moving to have a process to deal with this. Office365 for example offers IMAP as a migration path

Comment: @Drifter104 There are other providers with IMAP support. I would immediately rule out any provider without IMAP support. I would also think about backups to avoid the risk of losing emails in case the chosen provider suddenly decides to change or terminate the service.

Comment: @kasperd OK I have found a utility that copies emails from server to server through IMAP, so that's indeed the solution.